# Errors While deploying SSAS 2005 Cube on Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, ssas

I am stuck with something really nasty here. I have a SSAS Cube that was working fine till day before yesterday. Had some performance issues on the server and got cummulative patch 938077 on top of Service Pack2.
Since then I have not been able to deploy the cube - with a strange error -

**File System Error: The following error occurred during a file operation: Access is denied.**

I am administrator on the machine, have possibly checked the whole of file system for permissions. Have deleted the existing cube, stopped services, server, tried redeployment - nothing works.
Unfortunately I forgot to take a snapshot of pre-patch image, so cann't restore back. Only option I am currently left with is to rebuild the server, if I cann't fix this.

Strange but I cann't find anything on any forums about this.

Yes, one more strange thing related to this - I had SSIS package, to load DW (datasource for above cube), and strangely I have lost all my Data flow tasks. Something wierd is really going on and I cann't trace it.

Any suggestions or help would be great. I just cann't think of anything right now.

Cheers!!
Vineet

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, its more of a permission issue on the server than with the cube itself. Ran the SQL services under Local System account (after new security patches applied without us knowing it) and it worked fine.